# Why does this code cause the program to crash?

Tags: c++, crash, iterator

```
void gameListType::sortAscending() {

    nodeType<gameType> *current;
    nodeType<gameType> *next;
    nodeType<gameType> *prev;
    nodeType<gameType> *temp;

    temp = first;
    prev = first;
    current = first;
    next = current->link;

    while ( current->link !=NULL){
        if (current ==first){
             if (current->info.getPrice() > next->info.getPrice()){
            temp->info = current -> info;
            temp->link = next ->link;
            next -> link = temp;
            current = temp;
            delete temp;
            }
        }
        else if (current !=first ){
            if (current->info.getPrice() > next->info.getPrice()){
                temp->info = current->info;
                temp-> link = next ->link;
                next->link = temp;
                prev->link = next;
                current = temp;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        if(current == first){
            prev = first;
        }
        else{
            prev = prev->link;
        }
        current = current ->link;
        next = next->link;
    }
}
```

running this code will cause my program to crash, any ideas? This is basically to sort the items in a CUSTOM linked list. It apparently only crashes after the loop has completed once, so the second loop is the problem as to why it is crashing.

Comment: I notice there is no validity check on `next->link`. You could be getting a null pointer there.

Comment: When you set `current = temp;`, and then `delete temp;`, then `current` will point to an object that exists no longer. Later you access `current->link` etc., which will certainly be one possible cause of a crash.

Comment: First find out the exact line on which the program crashes.

Comment: You delete the temp. Just comment it. Works?

Comment: what's wrong with using `std::sort` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your code crashes because you treat `temp` variable as if it was pointing to a temporary object, but it actually points to one of the objects in the list you're sorting.

Take this simple path:

```
temp = first;
prev = first;
current = first; // temp == first and current == first, so temp == current
next = current->link;

while ( current->link !=NULL){          // true
    if (current ==first){               // true
        if (current->info.getValue() > next->info.getValue()){ // true
            temp->info = current->info; // temp == current, so nothing changes
            temp->link = next->link;    // temp == current, so current->link = next->link
            next -> link = temp;        // temp == current, so next->link = current
            current = temp;             // temp == current, so nothing changes
            delete temp;                // temp == current, so delete both temp and current
        }
    }
// ...
    current = current ->link;         // but we deleted current! segfault
```

Exactly the same problem is present in the `else if` block (there's a bit of code duplication in your sample). The problem is eliminated by creating a new temporary object for the `temp` variable. Note that it's enough to have a temporary for `info` alone:

```
if (current->info.getValue() > next->info.getValue()){
    // No need to mess with pointers here, current and next are advanced later
    // Bonus points for using a swap function instead
    InfoClass temp = current->info;
    current->info = next->info;
    next->info = temp;
}
```

This approach doesn't modify `next` and `current` pointers, thus fixing another problem in your function (i.e. `next->link` pointing to `current` instead of `current->link` pointing to `next`).

---

I want to address one other point here, which is that even when fixed, your function doesn't actually perform a sort; it only performs a single pass of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which 'pushes' the biggest value in the list to the right position (that is: the end of the list). Even when implemented correctly, bubble sort is an inefficient algorithm with a quadratic complexity in the average case.

[Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is a common algorithm used to sort lists. Alternatively, depending on what you're sorting, it might be beneficial to simply copy data into a vector, sort it with `std::sort` and reconstruct the list from the sorted data (this approach is simplest to implement and least error-prone, though merge sort is always fun to write).